# Status Code 412 "PreCondition Failed" while creating google calendar/Event from Google API in SALESFORCE

Tags: salesforce, google-calendar-api

I am using SALESFORCE GOOGLE CALENDAR API.
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Google_Calendar_API

There is a weird problem I am facing while creating Google Calendars or Events from the API: for some google IDs I am able to do All CRUD operations on google calendar BUT for some google accounts I am not able to INSERT and UPDATE the events/calendars on google (retrieval and deletion is still possible).
While Inserting Calendar/Events I receive Status Code 412 "PRECONDITION FAILED".
I have tried hard to find a solution but I have not been able to. Can anybody help?

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue using the Google .Net Calendar API. However I found that the problem was in my code.

This error appears when you receive an Event object, do a change to it, Update it using the Calendar Service, Change the same Event object again and then try to Update it again.
This second time the update will fail.

The reason is explained in this page: [Get Specific Versions of Resources](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/version-resources)

> If the entry (and its etag) has not changed since the last retrieval, the modification succeeds and the new version of the resource with the new etag is returned. Otherwise, you will get a 412 (Precondition failed) response code.